# Can JavaScript safely fetch data from untrusted domains?

Tags: javascript, network-security

My webpage has a need to fetch data in a client-side-initiated way from domains which may (sometimes**) be untrusted/attacker-controlled.

Does JavaScript allow to [safely] fetch data* from a domain which may be untrusted or attacker-controlled?

If so, what function is this?

---

Clarifications / Addendums / "inb4"s / P.S.:

*The data fetch protocol/format is not [yet] defined; not even as far as HTTP GET vs POST. **I have no preference on the data format** and may choose+implement it as required/appropriate, inclusive even of plaintext/delimited formats. **There is no requirement to use JSON**.

***Technically*, the domains (which may be arbitrary/user-defined!) must sometimes be loaded over HTTP; this threat model is isomorphic to fetching data from adversarial servers, especially in the context of roaming non-VPN'd network connections. (And, yes, the safe-handling of said untrusted data afterwards is out-of-scope of this question)

[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) "X": the driving project here is a web browser homepage/app which will load content (ranging from preferences and trivial widgets to outright *content*) from sources which may be user-controlled and may (at the user's option) reside on even non-ICANN domains (such as local domains, OpenNIC domains, etc.) It is entirely within-scope and expected/acceptable that some of this content will only be served via TLS, and may serve a variety of purposes ranging from "canaries" (of both MITM presence,  and mere network configuration checking) to outright location-specific data. TLS connections may or may not be available due to the aforementioned suite of reasons [that the domains are not pre-defined]; and there is content which must/ought/will be loaded even despite this case.

This is **not** a duplicate of [#29022794](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29022794/1874170). I have no requirement to use JQuery, and that question only asks whether `$.getJSON()` is safe to use on untrusted URLs (which, a. *it does NOT seem to be*; and b. *even if it were*, this question would be *asking after* the underlying function [that JQuery is calling], rather than asking how to use JQuery per se).

Comment: Maybe you can set up a server which will you'll trust of course. Your server then can verify if the payload of the untrusted party is 'good' or 'bad'... according to your standards.

Comment: Whenever I read questions starting with "Can Javascript safely..." I already know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penciling in a *circumstantial* yes: [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) *appears to be* safe to call on untrusted domains.

#### Justifications:

See [OWASP's page on AJAX vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_AJAX_Vulnerabilities_(OWASP-AJ-001)):

- Makes no mention of threats posed *to a client* by [this sort of] maliciously crafted server response; the only client-side risk(s) listed are *injections* of one sort or another.

See also [this similar question on Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/203945/187417)

- OP's very question (whether it is safe to **parse** an XMLHttpRequest to an attacker-controlled server as JSON) necessarily assumes that it's safe to **receive** such.
- Two users commented several times on the issue, discussing the implications of parsing said response, and **at no point questioned this underlying assumption**, only commenting on similar XSS injection attacks to those discussed by OWASP.

  - [ThoriumBR](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/54284/thoriumbr) (>5y member, 99.8th-percentile 2019 Information Security Stack Exchange user)
  - [Ry](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/8972/ry) (>8y member, Stack Overflow moderator)

While it's very hard to "prove" a negative, especially with security issues, the fact that there's an *ocean* of content online discussing risks involved in *parsing* potentially malicious responses (XSS injection prevention), dealing with the risks to the servers of such (CORS), etc.; without, apparently, even one *scrap* of discussion on this, means it's probably not one of the risks.

Answer (score -1):

No. You cannot do it in a browser due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) security protection. If you ever found one, it is a bug and the browser will fix it.

You can, however, do it on server side with [fetch API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Comment: (I tagged this question with the client-side `javascript` rather than the server-side `node.js`, and [I'm not particularly considering Node, either](https://itnext.io/no-way-to-prevent-this-says-only-development-community-where-this-regularly-happens-8ef59e6836de), so I'm not sure why you'd have mentioned it [rather than e.g., PHP](https://web.archive.org/web/20191030151711/https%3A//w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all);) but, more to the point: this project will hopefully/ideally be useable over "dumb" HTTP servers as well as simply local files.

Comment: That page on CORS looks quite relevant, though preliminarily it's looking like `You cannot do it in a browser due to CORS` is *the opposite of* the case: “Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin…These are the same kinds of cross-site requests that web content can already issue” ([Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS))

Comment: but, more specifically, "CORS" is just *the HTTP header security procedures around* cross-domain requests; what I am asking about is *the JavaScript client functions* to execute such; specifically, whether they allow a page on domain A to get *data* from domain B (with webmaster B's consent), without giving webmaster B *code execution access* on page A.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude - Do you expect other involved domains to grant you CORS allowance?

Comment: @PM77-1 the "other involved domains", which will be serving a to-be-defined data structure, over a to-be-defined HTTP method, will certainly be able to implement any to-be-defined HTTP headers deemed necessary.

Comment: but the scope of this question was *never the access control methods* to allow server B to serve data to A; the scope of this question was *how to prevent server B from having execution-control on page A, within the context of XDR*. If there's any way I could have been clearer about that in my question, please let me know.